# how to get value of array id of text field in jquery

Tags: jquery

> I want to get/set value of text field input in jquery

```
eg.
<input type="text" name="qty[0][0]"  id="qty[0][0]"> 
<input type="text" name="qty[0][1]"  id="qty[0][1]"> 
<input type="text" name="qty[0][2]"  id="qty[0][2]"> 
<input type="text" name="qty[0][3]"  id="qty[0][3]"> 
<input type="text" name="qty[0][4]"  id="qty[0][4]">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code.

```
$('input[id^="qty"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You in fact asked two different things.

> how to get value of array id of text field in jquery

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to get the array of ids

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kCZKT/)**

```
$('[id^=qty]').map(function(){    
     return this.id;
}).get();
```

> I want to get/set value of text field input in jquery

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kCZKT/1/)**

```
$('[id^=qty]').each(function(idx, item){
    this.value = idx;
    alert(this.value);
});
```

To access individual input you can use eq with selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kCZKT/2/)**

```
$('[id^=qty]').eq(0).val("1");
$('[id^=qty]').eq(1).val("2");

alert($('[id^=qty]').eq(0).val());
alert($('[id^=qty]').eq(1).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id attribute value is not according to the [standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

To get Id array

```
var array = $('input[id^=qty]').map(function(i, v){
    return v.id;
}).get()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uTPWm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try `val()` for single input ..

```
 $('input[id^="qty"]').val('test');  //set

 $('input[id^="qty"]').val();  //get
```

and for multiple input value in array use map()

```
 var array = $('input[id^="qty"]').map(function(index, value){
    return value.id;
 }).get();
```